# Click a element which is the last element in a row of a grid, and the number of the row is dynamic, in cypress

Tags: html, css, grid, cypress

The page has a grid. The grid has rows and columns. What I want to do is:
Each row has:
name email ready? date1 date2 togglebutton
I want to find a name on the page, and click on the togglebutton for that name. There could be 200 rows in a page.
Also, the name that I want to find could be in any row. Say, I am searching for janedoe@gmail.com
Based on the number of users signedup, janedoe could be in row 1 or row 97 or row 66. Once I locate janedoe@gmail.com on the page, how can I click the togglebutton?

I also want to paste the html here, but I dont know how to without it appearing in a single line?

Answer (score 0):

HTML code could be of great help, but assuming that each cell in the grid is `td` and the `td` with email is a [sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) of `td` with togglebutton, and the button has class `togglebutton`, something like this should work:

```
cy.get('td:contains("janedoe@gmail.com") ~ td.togglebutton')
```

It finds the cell `td` that contains text `janedoe@gmail.com` and then looks for a sibling of that cell: another cell `td` with class `togglebutton`.

Depending on your HTML structure it could look differently, but you should be able to adjust the code so it works for you.

PS to paste code, you may click CTRL+K or simply put your code between those characters: ``